# Why does this value equal to 'undefined'? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, object, tile

I have a function for finding on which tile the mouse is on:

```
function testTile(mouseX, mouseY){
    if(mouseX<mapArray[0].length*20 && mouseY<mapArray.length*20){
        var tile = getTilePosition(mouseX-10, mouseY-10);
        selectedtile.x = tile.xtile, 
        selectedtile.y = tile.ytile;
    }
}
```

and a function for getting the tile position given x and y

```
function getTilePosition(x, y){
    var xtile = Math.floor(x/20);
    var ytile = Math.floor(y/20);
return{
    xtile : xtile,
    ytile : ytile
    }
}
```

but when I call selectedtile.x or selectedtile.y I get a value of 'undefined'. What's wrong?

Comment: You have to define `selectedtile` first.

Comment: Oh damn, I had it defined as 'var selectedtile' instead of 'var selectedtile = {}'. Fixed it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your values are declared inside the function and are out of scope.

Do this:

```
var selectedtile = new Object() //de OUTSIDE All functions.
//de this works too: var selectedtile = {}

function testTile(mouseX, mouseY){
    if(mouseX<mapArray[0].length*20 && mouseY<mapArray.length*20){
        var tile = getTilePosition(mouseX-10, mouseY-10);
        selectedtile.x = tile.xtile, 
        selectedtile.y = tile.ytile;
    }
}

function getTilePosition(x, y){
    var xtile = Math.floor(x/20);
    var ytile = Math.floor(y/20);
    return {
        xtile : xtile,
        ytile : ytile
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait is 'var selectedtile = new Object({})' any different from 'var selectedtile = {}'?

Comment: Ok I see your comment above. This was the problem then... not setting `selectedtile` to an Object, just leaving it `null`

Comment: Why are you using `new Object({})` at all? Why not keep it simple? I think this is more confusing than helping.

Comment: Really? It's not awful people know `{}` is shorthand for `new Object({})`... Wait? I forgot! It's a *secret*!

`var super_secret_array_declaration = ['20459860']`

Comment: You are wrong. The equivalent to `{}` would be `new Object()`. You are doing something slightly different with `new Object({})`: You are creating an object (`{}`) first and then pass it to `new Object()`. Now, when `Object` is called with an object as argument, it simply returns that object. Proof: `var a = {}; console.log(new Object(a) === a);`. So, all you are doing is adding an unnecessary function call. It's the same as creating a number with `var foo = Number(42);` instead of just `var foo = 42;`. If you really want to use `Object`, at least use it correctly.

Comment: I sit corrected and am looking forward to refactoring my own code.